Отображение товаров в зависимости от выбранного города (wordpress, woocommerce)
При заходе на сайт, пользователь выбирает в каком он городе. Нужно сделать вывод товаров в зависимости от города. Магазин создается на Wordpress и Woocommerce с использованием дочерней темы. Так-же выбранный город должен сохраняться и если у пользователья есть ссылка на товар, который не доступен в его городе, то должно быть 404. Автоматическое определение геолокации не нужно.

Что делали? Что не получилось? Вопрос, должен содержать сам вопрос, а не только ваши намериния о желании что то сделать

@SwaD, в целом нужна помощь с реализацией, возможно кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей и может подсказать план (как правильно реализовать эту идею).
На данный момент моя реализация такая: через админку добавил товарам атрибуты городов, далее в functions.php проверяю, какой выбран город и вывожу товары с подходящими атрибутами, но мне нужно скрыть у товара атрибуты городов и мне кажется такой подход неправильный

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMCIKqL8iv0 (и я серьёзно)

"а данный момент моя реализация такая: через админку добавил товарам атрибуты городов". Жуть. Разные склады (с учётом товаров на них) - вот  верный путь.
